# Access an object returned by factory and modify in the view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am newer in AngularJS, so please correct me if I am doing something stupid.

I want to have a model object that can be changed from the view, some of the methods has to be public others private.

So I created a factory for the model

```
angular.module('nanApp.models', [])
    .factory('PoiModel', [function () {
        function Poi() {
            this.name;
            this.tags;
            this.address = {name: undefined, location: {lat: undefined, lng: undefined}};

            function addAddress(name, location) {
                this.address = {name: name, location: {lat: location.lat, lng: location.lng}};
            }

            function place() {
                return this.address.name;
            }

            function print() {
                return {name: this.name, address: this.address, tags: this.tags};
            }

            return {
                addAddress: function (name, location) {
                    return addAddress(name, location);
                },
                place: function () {
                    return place();
                },
                print: function () {
                    return print();
                },
                name: this.name,
                tags: this.tags
            }
        };

        return {
            createNew: function () {
                return new Poi();
            }
        }
    }])
;
```

From outside we can create a POI, name and tags are public as has to be binded from the view and address is private but has a public method to modify.

The controller looks like

```
angular.module('nanApp.controllers.pois', ['nanApp.services', 'nanApp.models'])
.controller('PoiCtrl', function ($scope, PoiModel) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.poi = PoiModel.createNew();

    vm.saveElement = function () {
        console.log(vm.poi);
        console.log(vm.poi.print());
    };

    vm.locationSuccess = function (name, location) {
        vm.poi.addAddress(name, location);
    };
});
```

Then from the view I am able to call locationSuccess and modify the address.
From the form I want to change the name, tags and then save.

When I am done and call saveElement() is printing that

```
Object {name: "a", tags: "b"}
Object {name: "", address: Object, tags: undefined}
  address: Object
    location: Object
      lat: 50.8176986
      lng: -0.12310700000000452
    name: "Marine Parade, Brighton, United Kingdom"
    __proto__: Object
  name: ""
  tags: undefined
  __proto__: Object
```

I understand that the first print doesn't print the address as it is private, but if I make it public is undefined.
In the second print, why name and tags are undefined?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it using a better sintax.

```
angular.module('nanApp.models', [])
    .factory('PoiModel', [function () {
        var poi = {};
        var address = {name: undefined, location: {lat: undefined, lng: undefined}};

        poi.addAddress = function (name, location) {
            address = {name: name, location: {lat: location.lat, lng: location.lng}};
        };

        poi.place = function () {
            return address.name;
        };

        poi.print = function () {
            return {name: this.name, address: address, tags: this.tags};
        };

        return {
            createNew: function () {
                return poi;
            }
        }
    }])
;
```